# "Unsupported Media Type" when i tried to send HTTP requests from Postman

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, postman

When I tried to HTTP requests I get "Unsupported Media Type" problem
I tried so my ways from others solutuins but it cannot help. I tried wrote same code again from scratch butit happend again.

[image: When I tried to HTTP requests I get "Unsupported Media Type" problem]
[image: This is headers part of my Postman]

My service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MarkaService {
    private final MarkaRepository markaRepository;
    private final MarkaMapper markaMapper;

    public MarkaDto markaAdd(Marka marka) {
        Marka marka1=markaRepository.save(marka);
        return markaMapper.markaToDto(marka1);
    }
}
```

my controller

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/rentCar")
public class MarkaController {

    private final MarkaService markaService;

    @PostMapping("/addMarka")
    public MarkaDto addMarka(@RequestBody Marka marka) {
        return markaService.markaAdd(marka);
    }

}
```

marka class

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Marka {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_marka_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_marka_gen", sequenceName = "seq_marka_id", allocationSize = 1)
    //@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String markaName;
    private boolean markaStatus;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "marka")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Model> models;

//    private List<Model> models;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Marka [id=" + id + ", Marka Name=" + markaName + "]";
    }
}
```

MarkaDto class

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MarkaDto {
    private String markaName;
    private boolean markaStatus;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the "Marka" class ?

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc I add marka class

Comment: can you please also add MarkaDTO ?

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc I add dto class also

Comment: Can you please add the pom.xml file. I think you have a problems with the depencies hence I am not able to reproduce the issue on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

In your `@PostMapping` annotation specify what type it consumes. Here is an example:

```
@PostMapping(value ="/saveUser", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: this solution does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Consumes annotation above your method MarkaDto:

```
@PostMapping("/addMarka")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MarkaDto addMarka(@RequestBody Marka marka) {
   return markaService.markaAdd(marka);
}
```

Comment: I added "Javax WS RS API » 2.0" for @Consumes annotation (If I added wrongly inform me) And run it again but result is the same

Comment: You should add "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" just lime it says on the example

Comment: @MichaelGantman I add as the example says. but result was the same